# How to play other formats (not mp4 or flv) videos with JWPlayer?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer, mp4

I want to play googledrive videos in jwplayer or any other web player with subtitles and video image. I have succeeded to do this in jwplayer but jwplayer supports only mp4 and flv video formats.

I want to play avi,wmv and mk4 formats too. Is there any other player that can do the task?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. There's no website player that can reproduce avi, wmv, mk4 files on modern HTML5 browsers (without plugins like Flash). 
Unfortunately you need to convert the files to the allowed formats depending on device/browser/player (common choice: mp4/aac)